# Simple Java library to load properties

Tags: java, configuration-files

Is there a simple Java library to provide programmatic access to values in a property file (e.g via annotations)? I have in mind something similar to the [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) library, but for key-value string property pairs. Some sample code I could imagine:

```
class Configuration {
 @Value(default=2, description="My important integer property") int integerProperty;
 @Value(required=true) String requiredStringProperty;
}

Properties props = load( ... );
Configuration config = (Configuraton)(ConfigParser.parse(props));
System.out.println("My required string propery has the value " + config.requiredStringProperty);
```

I have googled around for a while, but haven't found anything similar.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I think it's quite clear what the problem is: I'd like to parse a properties file to a Java object, maybe doing some basic validation.

Comment: nobody says that the problem is unclear, still youre asking to find a library for it which is off-topic. Describing the problem without asking for a library would be off-topic also. SO is a site to ask about specific programming problems, not about complete solutions

Comment: I'm asking if there exists an implementation to a pseudo-API I provided. Isn't this specific enough? What part of this problem would be appropriately specific?

Comment: Exactly - youre asking for an implementation. That is (for problems of a relevant size, with more than like 10 lines or smth) generally off-topic on SO.

Comment: Why would asking for an implementation be off-topic? I think the question is specific, it's "crystal clear" what I want, it's not subjective, so not a recommendation question in the sense of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question. True, I haven't said that now I write my own code to accomplish this.

Comment: As I said, I was talking about bigger implementations (like a complete properties library). Roberts comment from the meta-question you linked describes it pretty well:" We prefer to focus on programming problems, not requests for links to external resources. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a good search engine, and it's not a proxy for doing your own routine research."

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, I'll try to come up with a better wording for my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) libray

With this library you can read configuration from multiple sources, properties files being one of them.

Usually if you are using any dependency injection framework ( like Spring, CDI etc) you already have good support for injecting properties via annotations. But in case you are not using any, then it would be overkill to use the framework just for this small feature. If you want to roll out your own simple utility for this, take a look [here](http://nimana.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/using-properties-files-in-java-applications-and-autoload/)